# Is it possible to have a projection screen mounted vertically to the wall (not ceiling, not floor)?

Tags: mounting, projector

All I see are projection screens that are mounted to the ceiling, or pull-up (floor, desk).

I'm interested in installing it vertically, on the wall. So I can pull it to the left (or right, depending on direction).

I have a wall that is free and could host the case with the screen, just need to open it to the left. Yes, it must have a backing support so it stays flat.

I was thinking about getting a tabletop version (they have backing) and install it on the wall, however the screen size becomes weird because their ratio is now inverted (height becomes width).
It needs to be slim, so it doesn't call too much attention.

Is it possible? What would you use for this, even in a DYI setup (buying a roll of projection screen, then some kind of mechanism to be able to open/retract it).

Comment: Why do you want to pull it sideways. It can be mounted on the wall on pulled down or up. I do not understand how aspect ratio is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want but believe the weight of the screen will cause wrinkles unless you come up with some clamps to hold the top edge. It possibly a flexible rail that can be rolled but it would not fit inside the standard screen retract mechanism. A tape measure would not be thick enough but a 1” wide curved tape can be rolled up and may provide support to hang on a few points , that’s all I could think of.

Comment: Yes, it's a little tricky, but would be perfect for me and imagine other people might find it useful too. Not everybody wants something installed on the ceiling. I was also thinking about using a metal arm, that would fold down when not in use.

Comment: I agree, the screen sagging under its own weight is the likely result. You could have a track along the top, but that would be basically more trouble than just dropping it from the ceiling.

Comment: I think I understand and don’t question it could be handy. I can’t think of another way to go horizontally without some kind of support rail similar to a tape measure , that idea may work but it would need to be several inches wide to support the screen as you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an awning mount hung vertically. Generally, they will have arms that will lock to support the weight of the awning as it's hanging out over the window/deck/patio/whatever, so it should be reasonably sturdy enough to support its own weight when extended horizontally. I'd think that the weight of a screen would be less than the weight of an awning, so it should hold the weight.

The kind I'm thinking of has an arm at each side of the awning that ends up straight when the awning is fully extended, something like this:

[image]
<sup>Image from [outsidepursuits.com](https://www.outsidepursuits.com/best-retractable-awning/). No endorsement intended or implied - it was the first image I could find of what I was looking for</sup>

You'd replace the awning material with your screen material and presto, zappo, giant sidways-roll-up screen. If necessary, you may need to apply some bulldog clips to keep the top from sagging. This would be a roll-out, apply clips, watch show, remove clips, roll-up use pattern, and I can see that getting annoying, but that's what happens when you buck the trend.

You may want to contact the manufacturer to see about vertical deployment. I'm sure they'd tell you that it wouldn't work, but since it won't see any wind load (I'm assuming this is an indoor application), you *might* ignore them and call it good anyway. That's *your* call, not mine.

---

To be honest, though, if you don't want a ceiling mounted one, I'd get a floor standing one and call it good. When you're not using it, store it leaning up against the wall where you're planning on installing this. I'm pretty sure it will be cheaper and *much* easier in the long run.

Comment: I think your answer is kind of funny, if mounted sideways as the op asked how is this any different than a screen that pulls down ?

Comment: Since it's designed for outdoor use and subject to wind, rain, potentially snow load, etc, the (normally horizontal) aluminum/steel/whatever supports are likely to be much more sturdy than the wires used to support the edge of a roll-up ceiling mount screen, thus taking the weight of being deployed horizontally better, providing more tension for the screen material to keep it flatter, and, hopefully lasting longer. TBH, I don't think the OP will find what he's after purpose built, but this seemed to me to be a reasonable option.

Comment: Oh, and thanks, @EdBeal, it was intended to have just a touch of snark to it. Glad that came through. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount it vertically then i would suggest a  [fixed projection screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L9GF363).

You can mount any which way you choose.

OR You can   [make one](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diy%20projection%20screen),

OR Paint one on a wall.

Comment: Thank you, it needs to be something I can retract when not in use.